# Filling in the last two rows of a character table?

Tags: representation-theory

I have a hopefully simple question about character tables.  If I know all but two rows of a character table, and the character table is sufficiently large (say, at least 4 rows), do the orthonormality relations (for the rows and columns) uniquely determine the rest of the table?  Note that I am not asking for advice on how to find the two missing rows; rather, I want to know, if I happen to guess two rows that satisfy column and row orthonormality, must they actually be correct?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean finite dimensional representations of finite groups. In this case the answer is still "no" since you need to ensure the image of a $1$-dimensional rep (for example) is a subgroup of $S^1$ there are many orthonormal vectors in $\Bbb C^n$ who's coordinates don't form a group. This means even if you reduce even more, to the ABELIAN case, it doesn't have to be true.